# Using a Unicode format for Python's `time.strftime()`

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to call Python's `time.strftime()` function using a Unicode format string:

```
u'%d\u200f/%m\u200f/%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

([`\u200f`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f/index.htm) is the "Right-To-Left Mark" (RLM).)

However, I am getting an exception that the RLM character cannot be encoded into ascii:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u200f' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

I have tried searching for an alternative but could not find a reasonable one. Is there an alternative to this function, or a way to make it work with Unicode characters?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Many standard library functions still don't support Unicode the way they should. You can use this workaround:

```
import time
my_format = u'%d\u200f/%m\u200f/%Y %H:%M:%S'
my_time   = time.localtime()
time.strftime(my_format.encode('utf-8'), my_time).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Mind that Python 3 will behave differently, see my bug report (http://bugs.python.org/issue8304).

Comment: argh! this bit of info is needed by more than half the planet (well python users only) and it's found...just here...nice!

Comment: Be wary of using a hard coded encoding here -- the encoding used by `strftime` may depend on your environment.

Answer (score 4):

You can format string through utf-8 encoding:

```
time.strftime(u'%d\u200f/%m\u200f/%Y %H:%M:%S'.encode('utf-8'), t).decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read from a file as Unicode and then convert it to Date-time format.

```
from datetime import datetime

f = open(LogFilePath, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
# Read first line of log file and remove '\n' from end of it
Log_DateTime = f.readline()[:-1]
```

You can define Date-time format like this:

```
fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
```

But some programming language like C# doesn't support it easily, so you can change it to:

```
fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Or you can use like following way (to satisfy .%f):

```
Log_DateTime = Log_DateTime + '.000000'
```

If you have an unrecognized symbol (an Unicode symbol) then you should remove it too.

```
# Removing an unrecognized symbol at the first of line (first character)
Log_DateTime = Log_DateTime[1:] + '.000000'
```

At the end, you should convert string date-time to real Date-time format:

```
Log_DateTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(Log_DateTime, fmt)
Current_Datetime = datetime.datetime.now() # Default format is '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
# Calculate different between that two datetime and do suitable actions
Current_Log_Diff = (Current_Datetime - Log_DateTime).total_seconds()
```