# Python - format datetime with unicode string in Jinja2

Tags: python, templates, unicode, jinja2

Here is the code I'm using to format a `datetime` in Jinja2

```
# -*- encoding=utf-8

import jinja2
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

print jinja2.Template(u'''Hello {{ date.strftime('%Y 年 %m 月') }}!''').render(date=now)
```

There are some non-ASCII characters ('年月') in the argument of `date.strftime`. Jinja2 complains that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print jinja2.Template(u'''Hello {{ date.strftime('%Y 年 %m 月') }}!''').render(date=now)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Jinja2-2.6-py2.7.egg/jinja2/environment.py", line 894, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "<template>", line 1, in top-level template code
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u5e74' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Then I change that to

```
print jinja2.Template(u'''Hello {{ date.strftime(u'%Y 年 %m 月') }}!''').render(date=now)
```

(Notice the 'u' before `'%Y 年 %m 月'`) But it seems that Jinja2 doesn't deal with Python unicode literal. It complains that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print jinja2.Template(u'''Hello {{ date.strftime(u'%Y 年 %m 月') }}!''').render(date=now)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Jinja2-2.6-py2.7.egg/jinja2/environment.py", line 831, in __new__
    return env.from_string(source, template_class=cls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Jinja2-2.6-py2.7.egg/jinja2/environment.py", line 769, in from_string
    return cls.from_code(self, self.compile(source), globals, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Jinja2-2.6-py2.7.egg/jinja2/environment.py", line 493, in compile
    self.handle_exception(exc_info, source_hint=source)
  File "<unknown>", line 1, in template
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'string'
```

Could anybody please tell me the correct way for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably stupid, but did you try to format your datetime without using Jinja's templates (and using python formating instead) and then pass the string ?

Comment: It's not a jinja problem; the error is thrown by `datetime.datetime.strftime()` itself; the format needs to be a bytestring rather than a unicode, apparently. encoding it to utf-8 before passing it to `strftime` seems to work, but I don't know that it's easy to do that within the template.  (interestingly, the jinja2 documentation mentions `strftime` as an example of why jinja treats ASCII strings as `str` instead of `unicode`, but doesn't mention what to do if you actually need non-ASCII in your format string...)

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571515/using-a-unicode-format-for-pythons-time-strftime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571515/using-a-unicode-format-for-pythons-time-strftime), `datetime.strftime` does not accept `unicode` string. However, inside jinja `unicode` is always used.

To solve this dilemma, a solution I can come about is to write a custom filter, which first converts `unicode` to `str` and then back:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from jinja2 import Environment, DictLoader
import datetime

def strftime(date, fmt):
    return date.strftime(fmt.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')

env = Environment(loader=DictLoader({'test': u'''Hello {{ d|strftime('%Y 年 %m 月') }}!'''}))
env.filters['strftime'] = strftime
t = env.get_template('test')
print t.render(d=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
```

(Note you have to attach custom filters to an environment.)